# Ввод массива посимвольно

Tags: java, arraylist, scanner

При присвоении строки массиву, массив принимает строку полностью, а не посимвольно, то есть элементом массива становится вся строка. Как сделать, чтобы можно было принимать посимвольно? Какждый символ строки - элемент массива.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(sc.hasNext()));
        String f = arr.get(0);
        System.out.println(f);
        System.out.print(arr.size());
    }
}
```

Comment: Используйте метод строки toCharArray, чтобы превратить строку в массив символов. На строки разбивать не рекомендую, так как вы потратите больше места зазря.

Comment: Почему то метод toCharArray  просто создал массив , такой же , целиком из строки, не разбив ее на символы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Действия:

- Используйте `Scanner` для считывания введенной строки
- Разделите считанную строку на массив `String`
- Конвертирование массива строк в список строк

Пример:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String[] items = sc.nextLine().split("");

ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(items));
System.out.println(arr);
```

---

Ввел:

```
123 vasas
```

Результат:

```
[1, 2, 3,  , v, a, s, a, s,  ]
```

Comment: Спасибо, действительно)

Comment: @ЭмильМаннапов, [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)